# Using MySQL and SQL Server contexts in single Web API request

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

i have a web application with custom AuthHandler that uses MySQL connection for checking permissions and business logic, that is linked to MS SQL database instance entities
so, the problem happens when the MS SQL Context is creating:

```
System.ArgumentException
Additional information: Keyword not supported.
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetOption(String key)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder.set_Item(String keyword, Object value)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connStr)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.<SetConnectionString>b__18(DbConnection t, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 c)
```

contexts code:

```
public SqlServerContext()
    :base("SQLServer")
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
}

public MySqlContext()
    :base("MySQL")
{
}
```

connection strings in config:

```
<add name="SQLServer"
     connectionString="Data Source={};Initial Catalog={};Persist Security Info=True;User ID={};Password={};MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="MySQL" connectionString="Server={};Port=3306;Database=Test;Uid={};Pwd={}" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />

<providers>
    <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
</providers>
```

contexts are now injected with Ninject container:

```
    binder.Bind<DbContext>().ToConstructor(i => new SqlServerContext()).Named(GlobalConstants.Context.ContentCodename);
    binder.Bind<DbContext>().ToConstructor(i => new MySqlContext()).Named(GlobalConstants.Context.UserCodename);
```

for the first, i don't understant, why code is trying to build connection strings with `MySql` instances. so i've decided to create SQL Server context with implicit connection string:

```
public SqlServerContext()
    : base(a())
{
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
}

private static string a()
{
    var a = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder
    {
        Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient",
        ProviderConnectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = @"{}",
            InitialCatalog = "{}",
            UserID = "{}",
            Password = "{}",
            MultipleActiveResultSets = true
        }.ConnectionString
    }.ConnectionString;
    return a;
}
```

but there are errors something like: `provider name keyword is not supported`, `multiple active results set keyword is not supported` - that is characteristically for MySQL behavior. does have anybody solutions for that problem?

Comment: i'm not sure, that i understood your comment correct. setting MultipleActiveResultSets to False changed nothing. removing this parameter from connection string throws another exception: `Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL context was marked by attribute:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof (MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

that is recommended for MySQL contexts using EF. removing this attribute solving issue